# Using a recommender system with new user

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am using "implicit" package (https://github.com/benfred/implicit) to create  a recommender system in python. More preciseling, I am using the implicit least square algorithm.
The library is pretty easy to use, I was able to make predictions for already existing users, or to find similar items, no prob. But how can I make predictions for  a new user which was not in input data? My goal is to get prediction from a new vector of items (~a new user). All items exist in input data.
This library and other equivalent ones usually provide a predict method for user already existing in dataset.
My first attempt was to get a prediction vector for each item and sum them all. But it does not feel right, does it?
This seems like a common usage, so I think I am missing something. What would be the method to use? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you're recommending but for example if it is something like `movies` then to a new user we would just generally recommend the `most popular movies`. Then as we get to know more about the user we can use the usual matrix factorization.

Comment: If we haven't any prior knowledge about the user, this seem the right approach. But, what if I know some movies he likes but I know this specific user doesn't belong to learning dataset. Is there any way to make prediction without recomputing all matrix factorization?